# How to create interactive x y axes for bar chart using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to build a simply R Shiny app that displays a bar chart with both axes as interactive elements. I'll demonstrate what I've done with the built in flights dataset.

I'm able to build a static bar chart, but only get errors when interactive. I've tried colnames(data), names(data), and aes_string in the server function. I think the issue is that in the ggplot aes the x label is read in as string but after_stat(count) isn't. Unfortunately I can't find any similar examples on the internet.

Any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks

```
# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

# data
library(nycflights13)
data = flights %>% select(carrier, origin, dest)

# desired bar chart
ggplot(data, aes(x=carrier, y=after_stat(count))) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = origin), position = "dodge")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    # sidebar  
    sidebarLayout(
      selectInput(inputId  = "xvar",          
                  label    = "X-axis variable", 
                  choices  = colnames(data),
                  #choices  = names(data),
                  selected = "carrier"
      ),
      selectInput(inputId  = "yvar", 
                  label    = "Y-axis variable", 
                  choices  = colnames(data),
                  #choices  = names(data),
                  selected = "origin"
      )
    ),
    
    # main plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("id_main_plot")
    )
)

# server logic to draw histogram
server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  output$id_main_plot <- renderPlot({
    
    # Render bar chart
    ggplot(data = data, 
           aes(x = input$xvar, 
               y = after_stat(count)
               )
           ) + 
      geom_bar(aes(fill = input$yvar), 
               position = "dodge"
      )
  })
}

# create Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `input$xvar` and `input$yvar` are just character strings. When you map these on aesehtics in ggplot2 they will be treated as constants. To tell `ggplot2` that these character strings are names of columns in your dataset you could use the so-called `.data` pronoun. For more on the `.data` pro-noun in the context of ggplot2 and shiny see e.g. this example in [Mastering Shiny](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2)

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(nycflights13)

data <- flights %>% select(carrier, origin, dest)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    selectInput(
      inputId = "xvar",
      label = "X-axis variable",
      choices = colnames(data),
      selected = "carrier"
    ),
    selectInput(
      inputId = "yvar",
      label = "Y-axis variable",
      choices = colnames(data),
      selected = "origin"
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("id_main_plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$id_main_plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(
      data = data,
      aes(
        x = .data[[input$xvar]],
        y = after_stat(count)
      )
    ) +
      geom_bar(aes(fill = .data[[input$yvar]]),
        position = "dodge"
      )
  })
}

# create Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3217
```

[image]